# execute complex batch command with cmd /C

Tags: batch-file

I'm trying to run

```
 @echo off & for /l %%a in (0) do TaskList /FI "IMAGENAME eq prog.exe" 2>NUL | Find "prog.exe" >NUL || (echo "update" & EXIT)
```

as a one liner with

```
cmd.exe /C <----here -->
```

But cmd crashes immediately. When I put the exact same command in a batch file, it works.
How do I need to format my command to make it work?

Background:
I'm trying to self update (aka "replace while running") a c# executable, without creating an external batch script but with aid of "cmd /C".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the code you are running is not inside a batch file, the percent signs need not to be escaped, so, it is not `%%a` but `%a`

The full command needs to be quoted

```
cmd /c "@echo off & for /l %a in (0) do TaskList /FI "IMAGENAME eq prog.exe" 2>NUL | Find "prog.exe" >NUL || (echo "update" & exit)"
```

Comment: Oops, my fault. Thanks a lot.